# Data doesn't show in input date time picker

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to make a form contain date time picker. I am using boostrap on it. It works fine when selecting the date time, but if I use it to make edit form, the time date data not show in input date time picker.
Here's my code

```
 <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
     <input type='text' class="form-control" value="<?php 
        if($detail['EventStart'] == ''){
          echo $today;
        }else{
           echo $detail['EventStart'];
        }?>" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
   </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script>
   $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
   });
   </script>
```

Any help will be appreciate. Thank You

Comment: is it outputting the value in a format supported by the datepicker? it's worth noting that the _display_ format may not be acceptable for setting the default.

Comment: What's the format of $today / $detail['EventStart']? There's a requirement of format for the value in order for datetimepicker to understand it.

Comment: $today = 13/01/2021 14:00 $detail['EventStart'] = 2021-01-13T14:25:00

Comment: Try this   <input type='text' class="form-control" value="<?php echo (empty($detail['EventStart'])) ? $today : $detail['EventStart']  ?>">

Answer (score 0):

for by default date set you want to set DefaultValue using Javacsript Or Jquery... [visit this Page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_defaultvalue.asp)

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("date").defaultValue = "'.$detail['EventStart'].'";</script>';
```

note: DateRangePicker default support m-d-Y Date Format so you have to pass correct date format data...

for Convert Date Format...

```
$date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($detail['EventStart']));
```